# Search Element by ID inside Textarea and replace it

Tags: javascript

i have alredy been searching for hours and still cant find a solution in pure javascript. No Jquery.

What im trying to do: Find a ID #logo inside a textarea with ID #myare and replace the .src of #logo.

```
  function myFunction() {
    var logo = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
    console.log(logo);
    document.getElementById("myTextarea").getElementById("logo").src = logo;
// or
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0e7nLf8j/

I hope someone could help me out here. Would be awesome guys.

Comment: id's are unique, so you never need to chain the `getElementById` function like that. just call it off document always, as there can only be one id result.

Comment: What does this have to do with React?

Comment: *"Search Element by ID inside Textarea and replace it"* You cannot use DOM methods for that. The content of a textarea is not parsed and becomes part of the DOM. You could get the content, parse it, change it, serialize it and write it back to the textarea though.

Comment: On top of what Felix Kling mentioned - check your console for errors, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a hidden DIV

```
let dv = document.createElement("div");
document.body.append(dv); //Can use .prepend() instead
dv.style.display = "none";
```

with texarea's value as innerHTML,

```
dv.innerHTML = txtarea.value;
```

then find and replace desired #logo

```
document.querySelector('#logo').replaceWith(/*new Element*/ e);
```

element and then save `dv`'s innerHTML to value of textarea

```
txtarea.value = dv.innerHTML;
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhL7tkns/)

Comment: Thanks SkillGG, a well-described solution and Fiddle.